# Invoke route handlers on both, Successful Authentication and failure, for passportjs + Node.js + Express.js Rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, authentication, passport.js

Please take a look at this basic login/token process using passport basic strategy for a Rest API:

**the route:**

```
router.get('/token', authenticate.basic, controller.token);
```

**authenticate basic strategy:**

```
authenticate.basic = passport.authenticate('basic', {session: false});

/* implementation of the Basic Strategy*/
passport.use('basic', new BasicStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    authenticationService.login(username, password).then(function(user) {
        if (!user) { 
              return done(null, false, { message: 'Login failed' }); 
        }
        return done(null, user);    
    }).catch(function(e) {
        return done(e)
    });
}));
```

**token controller (route handler):**

```
controller.token = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        // TODO fix this dead branch 
        return res.json(401, {error: "Login failed"});
    }

    authService.issueToken(req.user).then(function(token) {

        var user = {
            user_id: req.user.id,
            access_token: token
        }           

        return res.json(user);

    }).catch(function(e) { 
        return next(e);
    });
};
```

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate) :

> By default, if **authentication fails**, Passport will respond with a 401
>   Unauthorized status, and **any additional route handlers will not be**
>   **invoked**. If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked
>   and the req.user property will be set to the authenticated user.

Is there a way to bypass this behavior and invoke the route handler even if the authentication fails ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Passport's "[Custom callback](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate)" feature.

Basically, you need to give the authenticate method a third argument to override the default behavior. This implies that the application becomes responsible for logging in the user, which is simply a matter of calling the `req.login()` method.

```
authenticate.basic = function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('basic', {
    session: false
  }, function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      // Authentication failed, you can look at the "info" object
      return next(err);
    }

    if (!user) {
      // The user is not logged in (no token or cookie)
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }

    req.login(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        // Something wrong happened while logging in, look at the err object
        return next(err);
      }

      // Everything's good!
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
}
```

Comment: I have no redirection, it's a Rest API

Comment: This is just an example to get you started.